# Как в markdown сделать ссылку для перехода к заголовку?

Tags: markdown

Нужно сделать ссылку с переходом к заголовку (прямо как в содержании).

Comment: @entithat добавьте первую ссылку в ответы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы создать привязку к заголовку надо сделать что-то вроде:

```
[Какой-то текст](#имя-заголовка)
```

[*Источник.*](https://gist.github.com/asabaylus/3071099#anchors-in-markdown)